# Cannot find name PageMethods

Tags: typescript

I have everything setup for calling a WebMethod of the aspx page from JavaScript but The PageMethods is not recognized.  I get the error **Cannot find name 'PageMethods'**.

I have the ScriptManager with EnablePageMethods="true",
I have the method public static SendQuote() {} with the attribute [WebMethod]

Here's an image :

[Image of the error](http://1drv.ms/1ze8nJr)

The js is added to the aspx of course since everything else works fine

Answer (score 2):

> Cannot find name 'PageMethods'.

Quickest fix: add `declare var PageMethods:any`.

Alternatively you will need to generate a `.d.ts` for your `PageMethods`

Comment: I tried and I still have the same issue.  PageMethods is null so unusable

Comment: Try create a `PageMethods.d.ts" somewhere, and add bas' line of code. Then reference your PageMethods.d.ts at the top of your screenshot file.  That should remove the error?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your solution.  What do you mean by baseline ? The somewhere is vague